RDP to VM connected to NAT network in libvirt
I am running virt-manager on my Debian system.
I am running a Windows 11 VM using NAT networking. I can't use bridge networking because I also use Docker and don't want to deal with all the issues it has.
My Windows 11 VM has internet and all that jazz. What I can't figure out is, how can I RDP from the host to the VM? The IP of the VM is not accessible from the host.
If it matters, my main network (that my host is connected to) is on 192.168.10.1/24 and the VM is on a NAT of 192.168.100.1/24.

I no longer have a virt-manager based system to test, so please bear with me. (1) are you sure the VM network 192.168.100.0/24 isn't available from the host (2) could you set up a separate host/VM network that can safely ignore all the Docker complexity but that allows the host and VM to talk to each other directly?

libvirt leverages a bridge and iptables for "NAT networking" (i.e., not "qemu slirp"). If you can't reach the VM from the host, it'd be either the firewall on the host or that on the guest.

I just had the same question for an Arch-based system, and this article was the answer: https://blog.raw.pm/en/install-qemu-kvm-virt-manager-archlinux/ . You could test it on Debian and provide an answer to your own question here, if it works.
